# Proving that $\sum \deg(v) = 2m$ for any Graph $G$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Here is My proof, please correct me if wrong, I try to be formal.

Proof by Induction:

Let $\sum \deg(v)=2m$ assumption... when #of nodes is $n=0$.
so here the equation is  $\sum \deg(v)=2(0)=0$ [true for 0] .... (1)

now if we add new node $w$, and connect it to node v then we expect that only the degree of $v$ and $w$ will increased by $1+1 =2$ , and

so doing that like the following:$\sum \deg(v)=2 + 2m = 2(m+1)$,
then our assumption is true because when we add 1 edge, total  number of edges increased by $2(m+1)$.

Is it correct and formal proof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written this only proves the proposition for connected graphs without cycles.  In your inductive step you add a new vertex and edge to an existing graph.  This restricts the overall types of graphs.  However, it is mostly correct, here is how I would modify it.

First, instead of inducting over the number of vertices in a graph $n$, use the number of edges $m$.  Now your inductive step can look like this: Suppose we have a graph $G$ with $m$ edges.  Remove one edge at random.  The resulting graph $G'$ has $m-1$ edges, and by induction, we know the proposition holds for that graph.  Therefore, $\sum \deg(v) = 2(m-1)$ for the subgraph $G'$.  $G$ is just the graph $G'$ with one more edge.  Since this edge is connected to two vertices in $G$, the degree of each of those vertices has now increased by one.  So $\sum \deg(v) = 2(m-1) + 2 = 2m$ for the graph $G$.

That would yield a full formal proof.

*Update*

For the base case you will need to prove the proposition for all graphs with $0$ edges.  Namely the graphs that consist of $0$ or more vertices and no edges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
you said that 'Now show it holds for the graph with the edge placed back in.'  what you mean mathematically ? could you please give more explanation for this point,

Comment: @TandeeHolwa  Updated

Comment: Now it is clear I will accept your answer, MOMENTARILY , let us go back to my assumption : why adding new node and then connect it to only one vertex 'v'  is not a general case, as you said this is not for all types of graph like cycle graph, where exactly the problem, is just because this assumption will jump over the situation of such graph like cycle and then lead to internal-proof for cycle graph that connected with  new node or not, etc...  just please for explanation, Thank you so much for your understanding me.. :)

Comment: I would say that is right.  The way inductive proofs work is that for an object in the set the proposition holds you need to be able to iterate through a finite number of steps to get to it.  Say e.g. a graph had a cycle with $n$ vertices.  So the issue is directly in your inductive step proof.  You add a vertex to a graph with $n-1$ vertices with one new edge.  There is no way to iteratively get a cycle from a graph in that manner.  In contrast, in my breakdown of graphs, all graphs with $m$ edges, come from a graph with $m-1$ edges (There are actually many subgraphs with $m-1$ edges).

Comment: could you please explain 'There is no way to iteratively get a cycle from a graph in that manner.' 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure how to explain it more than pointing out if you are always adding one *new* vertex with an edge to an *existing* vertex you will never create a cycle.  Try it.

Comment: yes sure, we will never get a cycle, my question why you need a cycle then ? is it important for our proof to keep the structure as it before ? is that what you mean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24977/discussion-between-tandee-holwa-and-muaddib).

Comment: any new suggestion please ?

Comment: Respectfully, I've done enough work as I am willing to do for one post.

Comment: Sorry, but you said that : adding a new edge will restrict all types of Graph, but there would be no restriction, because adding edge between two vertices will increase their degree by one, whatever the graph type is, so I do not think that it is a restriction, if so also removing edge also will restrict types of graph either.. ?