# What is the wrong in proving this Assumption?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the famous case of proving that total number of degrees in a graph $G$: $\sum \deg(v_G) =2m$.
By Using Proof by induction:-
for: $$m=0: 2m= 2*0 =0 \tag 1$$ is true ..

$(2)$...We add a new edge to the graph then the total number of edges will be $m+1$, and we observe that the new **edge** between two vertices is increasing degree of each node by 1  , so totally the degree of the new constructed graph $G'$  is increased by 2.
Then:
assuming: $\sum \deg(v) =2m$ is true, this will lead to that:-

\begin{align}
\deg(v_G') &= \deg(v_G) +2 \\[8pt]
&= \sum \deg(v_G)  + 2=2m+2 = 2(m+1)
\end{align}

which is again gives twice total number of edges in a graph. so the assumption is true #

Is This a formal Proof, because in one of my [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330909/proving-that-sum-degv-2m-for-any-graph-g/1330923#1330923) someone claims that:"adding a new edge will restrict the types of the Graph and could lead to unusual/non-intuitively remarks could weak the proof by some scene"?

Comment: By the way, if you don't understand my answer, you need to learn first-order logic first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that someone is correct, because you did not use induction correctly. You need a property $P$ such that $P(0)$ is true and given any natural $n$, if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is true. When you actually write down what you want $P$ to be, you will see that your proof fails. Try before looking below.

> Let $P(n)$ be true if and only if for every graph $G$ with $n$ vertices we have $\sum_{v \in G} \deg_G(v) = 2 E(G)$. It is easy to prove that $P(0)$ is true. Now to prove that $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$, you need to prove under the assumption of $P(n)$ that $P(n+1)$ is true. But $P(n+1)$ says "For every graph ..." so you need to make sure it works "for every graph ..."! You cannot start from a graph of $n$ vertices and build one with $n+1$ vertices because then you did not prove "for every graph with $n+1$ vertices" as required. Instead you must start with any graph with $n+1$ vertices, and try to relate it to some graph with $n$ vertices that $P(n)$ would say something about, so that it will tell you something about your graph with $n+1$ vertices.

Comment: but You know that the theorem state that is true for any Graph G, so adding edge in any graph will increase the degree of  the start and end vertex, why shall I re-proof that again.... that is a fact

Comment: What you said in your comment is irrelevant. Write down $P$ as well as what you must prove before you can use the axiom of induction, before we can continue.

Comment: That is great. But what is the problem about adding one edge causes some restriction on graph types as mentiond  here :*http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330909/proving-that-sum-degv-2m-for-any-graph-g/1330923#1330923(

Comment: The point is that if you do what you did in your question, you have not proven the necessary things that allow you to use induction. So the proof completely fails. You have to have complete grasp of that first. I didn't want to go into what you quoted, because it involves something called inductive constructions which I didn't think you will understand if you didn't understand induction itself. I recommend you ignore my next comment if you do not fully understand how to use induction.

Comment: @TandeeHolwa: One can inductively define the class $C$ of graphs that can be obtained from a vertex by adding edges. This is done via recursion, where at each step we create the class of graphs that can be obtained from a graph in the class in the previous step by adding one edge. The union of the sequence of classes produces $C$. Now what you wrote in your proof merely shows that the sum of degrees in any **such** graph in $C$ is twice the number of its edges. It does not at all prove anything about any other kind of graph.

Comment: @TandeeHolwa: I recommend that you edit your question and write down exactly what needs to be proven before you can use induction, and tell me so that I can check it. This kind of mistake with induction is a common one and it is not really your fault because I've seen many lecturers not teach it properly.

Comment: please come to my new link (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335037/how-to-prove-that-the-total-number-of-degrees-in-any-graph-g-is-sum-degv)